# rails fill model with data from another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

For now, I've got Three Models

```
# town.rb
class Town < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :buildings
end

# building.rb
class Building < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :town
end

# building_default.rb
class BuildingDefault < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

I want the following to happen when a User creates a Town :

1. Populate the user's `Building` model with records based upon the
   information contained in the `BuildingDefault` model.
2. Set each `building.town_id` correctly.

For example, lets assume Building and BuildingDefault have the attribute `:name` in common with each other. And BuildingDefault contains two records (it will actually contain ~ 125):

```
BuildingDefault.all 
# => <ActiveRecord::Relation [#<BuildingDefault id: 1, name: "cannon">, #<BuildingDefault id: 2, name: "archer">]>
```

Then a User fills out a form that creates a new Town. I want to do an `after_create` method which copies everything from `BuildingDefault` to `Building`. In this case Building would end up with:

```
Building.find_by_town_id(1) 
# => <ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Building id: 69, town_id: 1, name: "cannon">, #<Building id: 70, town_id: 1, name: "archer">]>
```

What's a possible way to facilitate this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should be enough :

```
after_create :set_buildings

  private
    def set_buildings
      BuildingDefault.all.each do |default_b|
        buildings.create(id: default_b.id, name: default_b.name)
      end
    end
```

Comment: Ok, this is more what I'm going for. BuildingDefault will contain approximately 125 records. Will it be too slow to loop through and create 125 items? Or is there a faster way to do it?

Comment: I think there isn't any other significantly faster way to do it. Since each default record will definitely require an SQL query.

Comment: Sorry for the basic questions, but is the code above intended to be used as one chunk, and where does it go?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are confusing with user_id and town_id or you really want user model also to be associated with building/town. If it's the latter, please update your code to include with a 'belongs_to' user association.

For now, I am assuming you want to associate towns and buildings only. It is a case of many_to_many relationships. In that case, there are two options I see.

- If all your buildings have no special attribute related to individual town,(i.e, building of type "cannon" has the same values for Town A or Town B), you can just associate `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship between the two creating a dummy join table.Then you can add all buildings to each town when it is created by following code:

  @town.buildings = Building.all

  @town.save!
- If there can be different values related to buildings for individual town, then you can set up a `has_many buildings, through: :building_town` relationship in Town model and puts those differing attributes on the intermediate model  which in this case is BuildingTown.

I don't see the need for keeping a DefaultBuilding model if all you do is  copy all over to the actual Building model.